# How can I make a discord embeded link

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I tried coding a Clickhere in my code but it doesn't work and instead it always sends [Clickhere] (link). I also tried the message embed. but it says that "discord is not defined". Here's my code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'name',
    description: "description",
    
    execute(message, args){const today = new Date().getDay();
        switch (today) {
          case 0:
             message.channel.send (
                'message');
      
            break;
          case 1:
               botInfo= '[Click here!](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360038398572-Hyperlink-Markdown)'
             message.channel.send (
                '[Click here!](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360038398572-Hyperlink-Markdown)');
             message.channel.send(botInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, hyperlinks are only available in embed messages, only in description and field values.

---

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
Embed.setDescription("[Click here!](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360038398572-Hyperlink-Markdown)");
message.channel.send(Embed);
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can do

```js
const {MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js");

const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setDescription("[Click here!](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360038398572-Hyperlink-Markdown)");
message.channel.send(Embed);
```